# How to write a code for the lambda method with pandas and random?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, apply

So I am working on this python code where I have imported a excel file in from my desktop. Currently in my code I am having problem with executing my lambda function. I am to use the lambda function in the apply() method for the data column(s) with outliers (i.e., z-scores > 3 or < -3), set the value for the outliers to null (i.e., np.nan), otherwise retain the original value.
I have types the line of code 2 different ways with the same outcome. However when I check to see if my overall code used the lambda function it did not and I don't know how to get my code to use the function instead of just running lambda as no part of the overall code.

This is the individual array for each datatypes after using the unique() method. 
[image]
Have already replace the strings in the array

The image shows the use of the sort_value() method used in my code as well as finding possible outliers for the z-score of the variable before inputting the lambda function into the code.
[image]

```
data.SalaryZScores.apply(lambda SalaryZScores:np.nan if SalaryZScores > 3 or SalaryZScores<-3 else SalaryZScores)
```

Or

```
data['Salary'] = data['Salary'].apply(lambda Salary: random.randrange(data['Salary'].min(), data['Salary'].max())if pd.isnull(Salary) else Salary)
```

Comment: could we see what `data` looks like?  and what does `data['Salary']` look like after you apply your lambda function?

Comment: I have added it into the question i asked

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what your snippets are doing as you haven't provided the code to produce any of the objects in your question. If I understand what you're trying to do the following approaches might solve your problem:

Using `.apply()` and `lambda`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create some data
data = np.arange(20).reshape(10, 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('AB'))
df

[Out]
    A   B
0   0   1
1   2   3
2   4   5
3   6   7
4   8   9
5   10  11
6   12  13
7   14  15
8   16  17
9   18  19

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x : np.nan if (x < 4) or (x > 10) else x)
df
[Out]
      A   B
0   NaN   1
1   NaN   3
2   4.0   5
3   6.0   7
4   8.0   9
5  10.0  11
6   NaN  13
7   NaN  15
8   NaN  17
9   NaN  19
```

Using `Series.between`:

```
df['A'].between(4, 10) # Creates a boolean mask between 4 and 10
[Out]
    A
0   False
1   False
2   True
3   True
4   True
5   True
6   False
7   False
8   False
9   False

df['A'][~df['A'].between(4, 10)] = np.nan # Uses ~ to invert the boolean mask and set values to np.nan
df
[Out]
      A   B
0   NaN   1
1   NaN   3
2   4.0   5
3   6.0   7
4   8.0   9
5  10.0  11
6   NaN  13
7   NaN  15
8   NaN  17
9   NaN  19
```